# How to change letter case in RStudio editor?

Tags: rstudio

I just read [Google's R Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml), and decide to be consist with the letter case in function names and variables. How to change letter case in RStudio's editor? To be specific, how to change words

- to all lowercase
- to all uppercase
- to captilized case (capitalize the first letter)?

Answer (score 15):

To Lower case you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Shift + U,
To Upper case you can use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + U

Answer (score 1):

According to Rstudio [support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203032528-Hotkey-to-toggle-case-i-e-UPPER-lower-Proper-):

> There isn't one [i.e., a hotkey] right now. The functionality is available under the Vim keybindings, though--with the editor in Vim mode, pressing ~ will toggle the case of the character under the cursor (or of the current selection, etc.)

Further information on Vim mode is available at [support](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/02/23/rstudio-0-99-preview-vim-mode-improvements/).